# Sitecore dictionary labels showing keys instead actual text phrases

Tags: dictionary

We have upgraded our website from Sitecore 8.2.4 to Sitecore 9.0.2. While on a local standalone environment the dictionary items are translated as expected, on a scaled environment (1 CM and 1 CD) the keys are being shown instead of phrases. 
Basically in order to fix this issue, I remove the temp/dictionary.bat file and I republish the

> /sitecore/system/Dictionary

folder with sub-items. This fixes the dictionary labels translation for a few hours, maximum one day, then the keys are being shown again.

Did anyone experience this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old issue which I could replicate on some solution of Sitecore 8 but it's strage is still on Sitecore 9.

On events `<event name="publish:end">` and `<event name="publish:end:remote">` you need to add a new handler for reseting dictionary cache :

```
<event name="publish:end">
  <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
   <sites hint="list">
     <site>website</site>
    </sites>
 </handler>
 <handler type="Yournamespace,DictionaryCacheClearer, yourAssembly" method="ClearCache"/>
</event>

<event name="publish:end:remote">
  <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
     <sites hint="list">
      <site>website</site>
     </sites>
   </handler>
   <handler type="Yournamespace,DictionaryCacheClearer, yourAssembly" method="ClearCache"/>
   </event>
```

Your class will be :

```
public class DictionaryCacheClearer
{
   public void ClearCache(object sender, EventArgs args)
   {
     Translate.ResetCache();
     Log.Info("Dictionary cache cleared", this);
   }
}
```